# Regex: find elements regardless of order

Tags: regex, sed

If I have the string:

> geo:FR, host:www.example.com

(In reality the string is more complicated and has more fields.)

And I want to extract the "geo" value and the "host" value, I am facing a problem when the order of the keys change, as in the following:

> host:www.example.com, geo:FR

I tried this line:

```
sed 's/.\*geo:\([^ ]*\).\*host:\([^ ]*\).*/\1,\2/'
```

But it only works on the first string.
Is there a way to do it in a single regex, and if not, what's the best approach?

Comment: If you need to get the values in separate variables, why use a single `sed` command? Use two.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest extracting each text you need with a separate sed command:

```
s="geo:FR, host:www.example.com"
host="$(sed -n 's/.*host:\([^[:space:],]*\).*/\1/p'  <<< "$s")"
geo="$(sed -n 's/.*geo:\([^[:space:],]*\).*/\1/p'  <<< "$s")"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/JEXz47), `echo "$host and $geo"` prints

```
www.example.com and FR
```

for both inputs.

**Details**

- `-n` suppresses line output and `p` prints the matches
- `.*` - matches any 0+ chars up the last...
- `host:` - `host:` substring and then
- `\([^[:space:],]*\)`  - captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than whitespace and a comma
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The result is just the contents of Group 1 (see `\1` in the replacement pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have tag/name to value pairs in your input I find it best (clearest, simplest, most robust,, easiest to enhance, etc.) to first create an array that contains that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can simply access the values by their tags:

```
$ cat file
geo:FR, host:www.example.com
host:www.example.com, geo:FR
foo:bar, host:www.example.com, stuff:nonsense, badgeo:uhoh, geo:FR, nastygeo:wahwahwah

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":|, *"; OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    print f["geo"], f["host"]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
FR,www.example.com
FR,www.example.com
FR,www.example.com
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've used GNU Awk to convert your delimited `key:value` pairs to valid shell assignment. With Bash, you can load these assignments into your current shell using `<(process substitution)`:

```
# source the file descriptor generated by proc sub
. < <(

  # use comma-space as field separator, literal apostrophe as variable q
  awk -F', ' -vq=\' '

    # change every foo:bar in line to foo='bar' on its own line
    {for(f=1;f<=NF;f++) print gensub(/:(.*)/, "=" q "\\1" q, 1, $f)}

  # use here-string to load text; remove everything but first quote to use standard input
  ' <<< 'host:www.example.com, geo:FR'
)
```